# How to use typescript triple-slash reference comments to import another module and use the functions?

Tags: typescript, import, module

Typescript's triple-slash reference may not be needed now, but I still want to know how to use it.

Say I have two files:

#### -- modules/a.d.ts

```
export declare function hello(name: any): void;
```

#### -- modules/a.js

```
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
function hello(name) {
    console.log("Hello, " + name + " (from a)");
}
exports.hello = hello;
```

Now I want to use it in another typescript file:

### hello.ts

```
/// <reference path="./modules/a.d.ts" />

hello("module a");
```

I write like this, but when I compile `hello.ts`, it reports errors:

```
hello.ts(3,1): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'hello'.
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I have a lot of misunderstanding about modules.

In order to make all things work, I have to do following changes:

#### Modify `modules/a.d.ts`

```
declare module 'a' {
    export function hello(name: string) : void;
}
```

It should have declared `module 'a'` in order to work with `/// <reference ...`

#### make `modules/a.js` a local npm package

provide a `package.json` in `modules` dir, with content:

```
{
  "name": "a",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "a.js"
}
```

And install it `npm install --save ./modules`.

At last, the following code can work

```
/// <reference path="./modules/a.d.ts" />
import {hello} from 'a';

hello("typescript");
```